# multi-device hybrid app fails to build - The certificate specified has expired

Tags: windows, certificate, visual-studio-cordova

I started playing around with deploying a multi-device hybrid app. today.  I am not sure the exact steps I took whilst doing this, but now when I try to build for windows 8 I get the following:

> Error 3   The certificate specified has expired. For more information
>   about renewing certificates, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478.
>   [D:\dev\client\source\myApp\bld\Debug\platforms\windows8\CordovaApp.jsproj]
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets
>   1772

There doesn't seem to be any way to configure or renew test certificates for this type of project.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to a coding error, the Windows Cordova platform has a temporary key in it that expired on 11/11/2014. Microsoft is actively working with the community on a long term fix. To work around this issue, create a Windows Store project (WWA), take the “_TemporaryKey.pfx” from the Windows Store project, and put it in your Tools for Apache Cordova project in following location:
•   CTP 1 or 2: res/cert/windows8/CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx
•   CTP 3: res/native/windows/CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx

This post by MS Open Tech has details and a certificate that [you can download](http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/11/11/cordova-certificate-issue-were-working-on-it/).

Comment: Thanks Gabriel that really had me stumped.

Comment: Please note that path for CPT3.0 is "res/cert/windows/CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx" (cert folder under res instead of native)

Answer (score 7):

Another way to fix this issue in CPT3.0 is to replace `CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx` under

`%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-windows\3.6.4\package\template\CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx` with the latest one from [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-windows.git;a=blob;f=template/CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx;h=90d7ab2208ce170d176a2ac8a60eb22fbc1cbf7a;hb=refs/tags/3.7.1).

Once you've downloaded the file, just rename it to `CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx`

This way you do not have to copy the certificate every time you create new project.